# How to fill array of object in one class by results from another class

Tags: php, multithreading

I have two classes as below

```
<?php
class firstClass extends Thread {
    public $Title;
public function __construct(){
    $this->Vita = "h"; //code with this line works
    $this->Vita = array();//If I define $this->Vita as an array, the variable from secondclass does not load into this variable.
}//construct
public function run(){}
public function function1(){
    $thread = new secondClass();
    $thread->start();
    $this->Vita[] = $thread->var1; // this line does not works. I cannot push into array
    //$this->Vita = $thread->var1; this line works
    print_r($this->Vita);
    }//function1
}//class first
class secondClass extends firstClass {
  public $var1;
  public function __construct(){}
  public function run(){
    $this->var1 = "Something";
 }//run
 }//class fetchLink

 $firstclassObject = new firstClass;
 $firstclassObject->function1();
?>
```

As you can see, I want to pass $var1 from the second class to a function to first class. I receive the $var1 of second class into first class, but I cannot push it into the $this->Vita variable when Vita is type array. If Vita is not array, it works fine.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you clean up your snippet to make it runnable? There are lots of syntax errors here.

Comment: pls give me sometimes, I do it runnable.

Comment: @georg pls check now. I debug the code.

Comment: $thread->start() should probably be called thread->run(). Definition of class Thread is missing.

Comment: Class Thread is a multithreading class standard of PHP. As far as I now, run is not explicitly called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could manage to solve the problem. It seems in a class that extends Thread, there is no support to modify the content of array.

So, I built another class that does not extend Thread on top of the other classes as below:

```
<?php
class main {
public $arry = array();

function one(){
 $thread = new secondClass();
 $thread->start();
 $arry[] = $thread->Vita;
print_r($arry);
}//function one
}//class main

$mainobj = new main;
$mainobj->one();

class firstClass extends Thread {
    public $Title;
public function __construct(){
    $this->Vita = "h"; //code with this line works
}//construct
public function run(){}
public function function1(){
    }//function1
}//class first
class secondClass extends firstClass {
public $var1;
public function __construct(){}

public function run(){
    $this->var1 = "HHHHHH";
    $this->Vita = $this->var1;
}//run
}//class fetchLink

$firstclassObject = new firstClass;
$firstclassObject->function1();
?>
```

I call the treads from the outer clas called main, and receive the value from threads.
This way it works.